# Storing Constant Data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, model

What is the best way to store a set of constants like country names, currencies, city lists in a rails app?

I was thinking of having a model named Constants that stores all this data and another model ConstantMaps that is polymorphic that maps the constants to the various other models

Is this a right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to have more models with semantic names, each with methods that reflect what a model should know about itself. Your models should group related data. For example, you could have a Location model with methods like Location#country that returns country names and Location#city that returns city names. Currency would be its own model because Location#currency doesn't make sense when you think about the fact that you would have to tell Location about its location.

Having a single model called Constants and another model whose only purpose is mapping is a very bad idea because it doesn't tell you what's in the model, and worse yet it would contain unrelated data. It will be more difficult to trace errors and extend features in the future.

The data should be stored in a database with tables that correspond with the model names. The model's methods query the database and return expected data. If there's some reason you can't or don't want to store the constant data in a database, each respective model class could have a hash stored in a CONSTANT variable (e.g. `CITY_LIST = {australia: ["sydney", "melbourne", "brisbane",...], brazil: ["san paulo", "rio de janeiro",...]}` and the methods query that variable instead of the database.

Answer (score 0):

If this list require frequent addition/change, consider storing them in your database. Otherwise, it is part of your code, every change requires a new deployment.